# WPF Custom Control EventTrigger Not Firing Or Animation Not Working

Tags: wpf, grid, storyboard, custom-controls, eventtrigger

I am having a go at creating a custom control( its just a custom grid deriving from Grid, I would like to keep it a Grid because of a few other things I want to try), my question is why doesn't the story board work when I am trying to trigger it from an EventTrigger, but works fine under a normal trigger my code is below:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:GridEx}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseRightButtonDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard >
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="300" Duration="0:0:1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="300" Duration="0:0:1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" >
            <!--<Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard >
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="300" Duration="0:0:1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="300" Duration="0:0:1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard >
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="100" Duration="0:0:1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="100" Duration="0:0:1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>-->
            <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource LiftEffect}"/>
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TranslateTransform X="-1" Y="-1" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="10" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The idea is pretty simple when the user holds down the right mouse button I simply want the grid to grow in size. I know the animation works because if I start from Trigger "IsMouseOver" it works fine, but nothing happens if I hold the mouse down?
And no its not a commenting issue :P

My Custom Control Derives from Grid.

*EDIT CODE ADDED*

using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

```
namespace WPFCCLIB
{

    public class GridEx : Grid
    {
        public static readonly RoutedEvent LeftMouseDoubleClickEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("LeftMouseDoubleClick",RoutingStrategy.Bubble,typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(GridEx));

        public event RoutedEventHandler LeftMouseDoubleClick
        {
            add { AddHandler(LeftMouseDoubleClickEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(LeftMouseDoubleClickEvent, value); }
        }

        static GridEx()
        {
           DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(GridEx), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(GridEx)));
        }

        void RaiseLeftMouseDoubleClickEvent()
        {
            RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new     RoutedEventArgs(GridEx.LeftMouseDoubleClickEvent);
            RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: The animation works fine for a standard `Grid` is there anything in your derived Grid that is interferring with the mouse events?, have you tried `RoutedEvent="Grid.MouseRightButtonDown"` ?

Comment: As far as I can tell no, I haven't explicitly added anything in that may interfere :/ But in regards to it working in a normal styled grid I have seen that it does work, that is probably why I am a little confused as to why it suddenly doesn't work.

Comment: I just setup a derived grid and the animation works fine there too, could you post the code from your derived grid, does it have its own template?

Comment: I have added the rest of the code in :)

Comment: I copy pasted your derived class and the animation works fine, is there a `PreviewMouseRightButtonDown` on your main window somewhere overridding this.

Comment: Now I am just confused :/ the windows is blank atm, it only adds the grid to window. is there anyway to step through the animation and see what is happening?

Comment: Comment before might be a little confusing :P The window is blank apart from the custom grid element :) And no there is no Previewing done either. I have also changed where the code goes (ie was in a separate assembly ini. but i moved it) but still no avail

Comment: I have posted my test code below if it helps, try copy pasting that and see if it works at your end

Answer (score 0):

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication10"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="325" Width="422" Name="UI">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:GridEX}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseRightButtonDown">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard >
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="300" Duration="0:0:1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="300" Duration="0:0:1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <local:GridEX Background="Blue" />

</Window>
```

Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication10
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class GridEX : Grid
    {
        public static readonly RoutedEvent LeftMouseDoubleClickEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("LeftMouseDoubleClick", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(GridEX));

        public event RoutedEventHandler LeftMouseDoubleClick
        {
            add { AddHandler(LeftMouseDoubleClickEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(LeftMouseDoubleClickEvent, value); }
        }

        static GridEX()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(GridEX), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(GridEX)));
        }

        void RaiseLeftMouseDoubleClickEvent()
        {
            RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(GridEX.LeftMouseDoubleClickEvent);
            RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works indeed but only because the style is defined in Windows.Resources, if you were to create a custom control and have the code in the Generic.xaml I don't think that it will work :/ the  Mouse Over Trigger Fires but not the Event. When the code is in the Generic.xaml file.

Comment: Then it sounds like you have not loaded the generic.xaml into the applicatin resources properly, Generic.xaml acts no differnt to any other ResourceDictionary

Comment: Yea I was thinking that when I was writing up the last comment, the only thing that made me unsure about that idea was the fact that the animation works fine when it was run under the IsMouseOver Trigger, but i shall have a look in to that :)